# Writing data to tables in Azure Sql Database via Azure Function causes deadlock

Tags: transactions, azure-sql-database, deadlock, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm sitting here trying to figure out a way to solve a problem I have with deadlocks when writing data to database via Azure function.

What I'm doing in the workflow is:

- Getting data/content via Logic App from Servicebus queue.
- Sending the data to a Azure function.
- Processing the data in the Azure Function by extracting all the importent 
  data from the object and enqueue the inserts before making a transaction to the Azure SQL database.

But because the logic app starts "threading up" / starts many "instances" when the transaction to the database is writing data to the same tables as another insert transaction I get deadlocks.

Does anyone know of any good ways to solve this or maybe some known techniques to tackle such a problem?

Comment: Please read the following: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/774

Comment: Are you using a Stored Procedure?  Are you doing more then just inserting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Logic Apps to handle Service Bus messages in Azure Functions. Functions have [Service Bus Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) to do that directly within Function Apps.

When you do that, you can control the amount of parallel executions by changing [`host.json`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json) file. For Service Bus the parameter is `maxConcurrentCalls`, which is 16 by default, but you can set it to 1.

Of course, that will limit the throughput that you can expect from your Function, since all messages on an app instance will be processed sequentially. So you need to balance the parameters for your specific use case.

Comment: Hmm, ok well the thing is i am doing some stuff in between the different connectors in the workflow above. Is there still any way to control the maxConcurrentCalls even though the function is part of the logic app?